# Flexibility on opening multiple Cash ISAs in one tax year

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, isa

I expect this question is UK-specific.

I have a UK ISA with provider A. I have not yet credited any money into this ISA in this tax year yet. The interest rate is poor, so I'd like to open a new ISA with provider B, and transfer all the funds into there (an ISA transfer, not a regular BACS transfer).

I'd also like to open up a new ISA with provider C (on the basis I don't like to "keep all my eggs in one basket"). Can I do this, and add new funds into ISA C, from a regular account? I think this is possible, since I'm not adding new funds to ISA B, but I cannot find any definitive explanation.

Would be great if you can provide some official reference too :)

Comment: I cannot mark it as such, but just discovered [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/can-i-open-two-cash-isas-in-one-year-or-for-new-savings-and-one-for-transfer?rq=1) which is essentially a duplicate, and answers my question.

Comment: I've started the close-as-duplicate process to [Can I open two cash ISAs in one year, or for new savings and one for transfer?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/can-i-open-two-cash-isas-in-one-year-or-for-new-savings-and-one-for-transfer).